# How to send stdout of a ssh command in a file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I'd like to send the output the stdout of a ssh command in a file but this file remains empty when I read it.

```
# ssh -o "BatchMode=yes" -o "ConnectTimeout=5" admin@10.10.10.10 > /var/tmp/.result.txt
ssh: connect to host 10.10.10.10 port 22: Connection timed out
# cat /var/tmp/.result.txt
#
```

How to do so? Thanks.

Comment: Your connections fails, and what you see is the error output. What output you want it to redirect?

Comment: Oops, your answer made me realize that I have to send the stderr! Actually I wanted to send the error output in my file... :)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww this command could well form part of a shell script so I don't see how it is off-topic.

Comment: @arco444 - As written its just another question asking for help with an unrelated command. There are more appropriate sites for those questions. I'm also aware of the "in a script" trick to try to bring them back on topic. I'm usually not swayed unless the code of a real script is offered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass regular *stdout* to a file, your command does that.
Your issue is you get an **error**; and this is printed to *stderr*. To pass stderr you need to add this to your command

```
ssh -o "BatchMode=yes" -o "ConnectTimeout=5" admin@10.10.10.10 > /var/tmp/.result.txt 2>1&
```

This tells bash to redirect output to .results.txt, and then redirect stderr to stdout, so they both are printed to the file. It reuses the file descriptor which stdout uses.